# Custom analyzer in Tire Elastic not working with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, elasticsearch, tire

I am still doing something wrong. 
Could somebody pls help me?
I want to create a custom analyzer with ascii filter in Rails + Mongoid.
I have a simple model product which has field name.

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name

  settings analysis: {
      analyser: {
        ascii: {
          type: 'custom',
          tokenizer: 'whitespace',
          filter: ['lowercase','asciifolding']
        }
      }
   }

   mapping do
     indexes :name, analyzer: 'ascii'
   end

end

Product.create(name:"svíčka")
Product.search(q:"svíčka").count #1
Product.search(q:"svicka").count #0 can't find - expected 1

Product.create(name:"svicka")
Product.search(q:"svíčka").count #0 can't find - expected 1
Product.search(q:"svicka").count #1
```

And when I check the indexes with elasticsearch-head I expected that the index is stored without accents like this "svicka", but the index looks like this "Svíčka".

What am I doing wrong?

When I check it with API it looks OK:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?tokenizer=whitespace&filters=asciifolding' -d 'svíčka'

{"tokens":[{"token":"svicka","start_offset":0,"end_offset":6,"type":"word","position":1}]}

http://localhost:9200/development_imango_products/_mapping
{"development_imango_products":{"product":{"properties":{"name":{"type":"string","analyzer":"ascii"}}}}}

curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/development_imango_products/_analyze?field=name' -d 'svíčka'
{"tokens":[{"token":"svicka","start_offset":0,"end_offset":6,"type":"word","position":1}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check how you are actually indexing your document using the [analyze api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-analyze.html).

You need also to take into account that there's a difference between what you index and what you store. What you store is returned when you query, and it is exactly what you send to elasticsearch, while what you index determines what documents you get back while querying.

Using the asciifolding is a good choice for you usecase, it should return results either query ing for svíčka or svicka. I guess there's just a typo in your settings: `analyser` should be `analyzer`. Probably that analyzer is not being used as you'd expect.

**UPDATE**
Given your comment you didn't solve the problem yet. Can you check what your mapping looks like (`localhost:9200/index_name/_mapping`)? The way you're using the analyze api is not that useful since you're manually providing the text analysis chain, but that doesn't mean that chain is applied as you'd expect to your field. Better if you provide the name of the field like this:

curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/index_name/_analyze?field=field_name' -d 'svíčka'

That way the analyze api will rely on the actual mapping for that field.

**UPDATE 2**
After you made sure that the mapping is correctly submitted and everything looks fine, I noticed you're not specifying the field that you want to to query. If you don't specify it you're querying the [`_all`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/all-field.html) special field, which contains by default all the field that you're indexing, and uses by default the [`StandardAnalyzer`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/standard-analyzer.html). You should use the following query: `name:svíčka`.

Comment: When I check it whit API, everything seems to be OK. But the typo fix didn't help.

Comment: What do you mean it didn't help? Probably you have other issues too but with that typo it would never work. I'm going to update my answer with some more hints.

Comment: I agree that the typo would never work and I thank you for this. Such a stupid bug. I appreciate very much that three people are spending time with my issue unfortunately my reputation is to low for voting. I've udpated my question with API results. Thx

Comment: Everything looks fine, I guess you just need to specify the field that you want to query like `name:svíčka`. Look at my updated answer to know why.

Comment: Maaaaaaaan, that's it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @javanna You just solved my 2 week old problem, I just had to specify the query to the field... The question should be edited to add your answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

elasticsearch needs settings and mapping in a single api call. I am not sure if its mentioned in tire docs, but I faced a similar problem, using both settings and mapping when setting up tire. Following should work:

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document
  # include tire stuff

  field :name

  settings(self.tire_settings) do
    mapping do
      indexes :name, analyzer: 'ascii'
    end
  end

  # this method is just created for readablity, 
  # settings hash can also be passed directly
  def self.tire_settings
    {
      analysis: {
        analyzer: {
          ascii: {
            type: 'custom',
            tokenizer: 'whitespace',
            filter: ['lowercase','asciifolding']
          }
        }
      }
    }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your notation for settings/mappings is incorrect, as @rubish suggests, check documentation in https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/lib/tire/model/indexing.rb (no question the docs should be better)
2. Always, always, always check the mapping of the index to see if your desired mapping has been applied.
3. Use the Explain API, as @javanna suggests, to check how your analyzing chain works quickly, without having to store documents, check results, etc.

Comment: Karmi could you please show me, how the notation would look like for this example? I red the whole DOC couple times and I have no idea, what I am doing wrong. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Please note that It is very important to add two lines in a model to make it searchable through Tire. Your model should look like

```
  class Model
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
    include Tire::Model::Search
    include Tire::Model::Callbacks

    field :filed_name, type: String

    index_name "#{Tire::Model::Search.index_prefix}model_name"
    settings :analysis => {
        :analyzer => {
            "project_lowercase_analyzer" => {
                "tokenizer" => "keyword",
                "filter"  =>  ["lowercase"],
                "type" => "custom"
                }
            },
        }  do
     mapping do
       indexes :field_name, :boost => 10, :type => 'String', :analyzer => 'standard', :filter => ['standard', 'lowercase','keyword']
       end
     end

    def self.search( params = {} )
      query = params[:search-text_field_name_from_form]
      Model.tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 5) do
      query { string query, default_operator: "AND" } if query.present?
    end
  end
```

You can change the index_name(should be unique) and the analyzer

And Your controller would be like

```
def method_name
  @results = Model.search( params ).results
end
```

You can use @results in your view. Hope this may help you.